# Prove or disprove : $\det(A^k + B^k) \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This question came from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830010/deta-b-geq-0-implies-detak-bk-geq-0-if-a-b-commute). As the OP hasn't edited his question and I really want the answer, I'm adding my thoughts.

> Let $A, B$ be two real $n\times n$ matrices that commute and $\det(A + B)\ge 0$.
>   Prove or disprove : $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}^*$
>   $$\det(A^k + B^k) \geq 0$$

**What I think about it**
I think we can consider two cases : k even and k odd.
For k even, the result is pretty easy considering $$\det(A^{2k}+B^{2k})=\det(A^{k}+iB^{k}){\det(A^{k}-iB^{k})}=\det(A^{k}+iB^{k})\overline {\det(A^{k}+iB^{k})}\ge 0$$
For k odd, I thought about this equality but I don't know if it can help
$$A^{2k+1}+B^{2k+1}=(A+B)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-1)^i A^{2k-i}B^{i}\right)$$
so $$\det(A^{2k+1}+B^{2k+1})\ge 0 \iff \det\left(\sum_{i=0}^{2k} (-1)^i A^{2k-i}B^{i}\right)\ge 0$$

Comment: Interesting, it means that $det(A^2 + B^2)$ is always non-negative!

Comment: @PA6OTA If AB=BA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint :

If $k=2p$ then $A^k+B^k = (A^p+iB^p)(A^p-iB^p)$ and use that $\det \overline{M}=\overline{\det M}$. In this case, the hypothesis $\det(A+B)\ge 0$ is useless.

If $k=2p+1$, use the factorization $A^k+B^k = (A+B)\prod_{m=1}^p (A+e^{\frac{2im\pi}{2p+1}}B)(A+e^{-\frac{2im\pi}{2p+1}}B)$ and then use the trick of the even case.

Comment: Nice work, beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proof for $det(B) \ne 0$. We have
$$
det(A+B)=det(B)det(AB^{-1}+I)=det(B)det(PJ_{AB^{-1}}P^{-1}+I)=det(B)(\lambda _1 +1)\cdots (\lambda _n + 1)
$$
and
$$
det(A^k+B^k)=det(B^k)det(A^k B^{-k} + I)=det(B^k)det(PJ_{AB^{-1}}^kP^{-1}+I)=det(B)^k({\lambda _1}^k +1)\cdots ({\lambda _n}^k + 1),
$$
where $\lambda _i$ are eighnvalues of $AB^{-1}$. There are four possible cases:
$$1)det(B)\gt0,k~is~odd$$ 
$$1)det(B)\gt0,k~is~even$$
$$1)det(B)<0,k~is~odd$$
$$1)det(B)<0,k~is~even$$.
It is easy to see that in all these cases $det(A^k+B^k)\ge0$.

Comment: Can you see it for even $k$.

Comment: Can you see that complex roots have no effect on sign?

Comment: but $(1+{\lambda _i}^k)(1+\overline{\lambda _i}^k)$ is positive.

Comment: $(1+ \lambda _i)$ and $(1 + {\lambda _i}^k)$ have the same sign if $\lambda _i$ is real.

Comment: First, I didn't say that $\lambda _i$ shouldn't be complex. And second yes.

Comment: It means that $(\lambda _1 +1)\cdots (\lambda _n + 1)$ and $({\lambda _1}^k +1)\cdots ({\lambda _n}^k + 1)$ have the same sign and as for odd $k$ $~~$   $det(B)$ and $det(B^k)$ have the same sign too, the $det(A+B)$ and $det(A^k + B^k)$ have the same sign.

Comment: But I said that complex roots have no result on sign.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you so much ;) !!!

Comment: You are welcome.