# Show $\det(A + B) \geq 0$ implies $\det(A^k + B^k) \geq 0$ if $A, B$ commute

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be two real $n\times n$ matrices that commute. Assume $\det(A + B) \geq 0$. Show then that $\det(A^k + B^k) \geq 0$ for all $k \geq 1$.

I believe what must happen is find some factorization of $A^k + B^k$ using commutativity of $A, B$. then we may find some squared terms, which would imply that the determinant is greater than zero. Not sure what factorizations would help.

Or perhaps use the fact the $A, B$ can be simultaneously put in upper triangular form by commutativity.

Comment: That last idea is a winner.

Comment: You already asked this before, right?

Comment: Yes and it was strangely rejected. What was wrong with that post?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830376/prove-or-disprove-detak-bk-geq-0/830521#830521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

If $k=2p$ then $A^k+B^k = (A^p+iB^p)(A^p-iB^p)$ and use that $\det \overline{M}=\overline{\det M}$.

If $k=2p+1$, factorize $A^k+B^k$ by $A+B$ and then use the trick of the even case.

Comment: But once you factorize out $A+B$ it's no longer in $A^k + B^k$ form.